# css class not removing in template preprocess

Tags: theming

I have the following code.

```
function template_preprocess_image(&$vars) {        

     if($vars['style_name'] == 'thumbnail'){        
        $vars['attributes']['class'][]='';
        unset($vars['attributes']['class']);
        $vars['attributes']['class'][] = 'media-object';        
       }

}
```

I am not able to remove img-responsive class from the this  field. I have tried several ways but not luck. Please help me.

Comment: check this out https://www.drupal.org/node/2315471